# Change font size of superscript text in a dynamic html string in iOS Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, nsattributedstring

We have some html that contains superscript returned from Wordpress that we'd like to turn into a string for display in an iOS app, for example:

"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry <sup>1</sup>"

We are converting this into an NSAttributed string and applying a font and fontsize to it, however, the superscript is rendered at the same size as the main test. How would we apply a smaller font size to the superscript where the text is dynamic i.e. we don't know the rename in advance?

Comment: You can enumerate attributes looking for the superscript one, and change its font size.

Comment: On iOS it appears you can't use `NSAttributedStringKey.superscript`, which is available on macOS, because iOS only has a subset of keys, so you must find another way, e.g. enumerating the attribute `NSAttributedStringKey.font` and examining the `.ascender` to determine which is the superscript element.